# r lang and extract meta description from facebook page

Tags: r, facebook-opengraph

```
con=file("https://www.facebook.com/groups/368965769950169/","r",blocking=FALSE)
page=readLines(con)
d=grep('<title id="pageTitle">',page,perl=TRUE,value=TRUE)
res2=str_match(d,'"og:description\" content(.*?)/>')
Run

"=\"&#x200f;&#x200e;Super Healthy Kids&#x200e;&#x200f;. &#x200f;&#x200f;&#x663;&#x66b;&#x663;&#xa0;&#x645;&#x644;&#x64a;&#x648;&#x646;&#x200f; &#x62a;&#x633;&#x62c;&#x64a;&#x644; &#x625;&#x639;&#x62c;&#x627;&#x628;&#x200f;. &#x200f;&#x200e;We love making healthy food fun, simple, and delicious!  With recipes, strategies, tips, and more!&#x200e;&#x200f;\" "
```

But I need only `"We love making healthy food fun, simple, and delicious!  With recipes, strategies, tips, and more!"`

*How I can convert this latin1 strings to Arabic language and english language to save them in a text file*

`"=\"&#x200f;&#x200e;Super Healthy Kids&#x200e;&#x200f;. &#x200f;&#x200f;&#x663;&#x66b;&#x663;&#xa0;&#x645;&#x644;&#x64a;&#x648;&#x646;&#x200f; &#x62a;&#x633;&#x62c;&#x64a;&#x644; &#x625;&#x639;&#x62c;&#x627;&#x628;&#x200f;. &#x200f;&#x200e;"`